# How to insert RichLink (Chip Block) in Google Docs using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

[image]

Google Docs has recently introduced a feature where we can refer to

- Date
- Person
- Google Drive Document

in the form of a **Chip Block** (as shown in the picture above). The **Document-A** already exists in Google Drive.

Currently the only way to generate such Chip Block is to manually hover the document link and then click `Replace URL - Chip` in the pop up modal that appears.

I am trying to generate such chip block using Google App Script but have not been successful so far.

[Rich Link Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/rich-link?hl=en) does not have any code snippet or method to add a Rich Link inside a document.

[Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document?hl=en) page also doesn't have detail regarding how to insert a Rich Link.

I wonder whether the feature is not yet implemented in the `Google App Script Api`

**EDIT**

As mentioned by [Stephen Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9788548/stephen-shaw) this issue has been flagged on Google Issue Tracker [Create and insert smart chips](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225584757)
 by [maclir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432239/maclir).
Hoping for an early implementation of this feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The smart chips can be retrieved using the methods released on August 23, 2021. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#august_23_2021). But, unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for inserting the smart chips. Although I checked about this at both Google Document service and Google Docs API, I couldn't find the methods for this. So, I think that is the current answer.

And also, when I checked the Google issue tracker, I couldn't find anything about your goal. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) So, how about reporting your goal as a future request at the issue tracker?

Comment: I created [this request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225584757).

Answer (score 2):

There is now a Issue Tracker on [Create and insert smart chips](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225584757) that has 161 votes.

I use a workaround for insert smart chips.  My Google Doc Addon inserts it as a link.  When the user hovers over the link, the Google Docs interface gives them an option of converting to a SmartChip

```
let urlDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getUrl();
let para = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().insertParagraph(index,urlDoc);
para.setLinkUrl(urlDoc);
```

[View of cursor hovering over link, with option to convert to chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBiNH.jpg)