# Script to copy template table. Dropdown boxes error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu, google-docs, dropdownbox

​​I have created a script that copy template table from one docs to another.

[image]

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Templates')
      .addItem('some_items', 'appendTemplate')
      .addToUi();
}

​function appendTemplate() {
    var sourcedoc = DocumentApp.openById("DocID");
    var sourcebody = sourcedoc.getBody();
    var tables = sourcebody.getTables();
    var table = tables[0].copy();
    var destdoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var destbody = destdoc.getBody();
    var x = destbody.appendTable(table)
}
```

When I exec this script the table correctly copy to target document but dropdown boxes are without default colours.

[image]

when I tried to click any of them I got an error "unable to load file".

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in Google Documents engine.

Answer (score 1):

As the time this answer was posted, the Documents Service (Class DocumentApp) hasn't methods to handle dropdowns, only for Smart Chips (see [Release note August 23, 2021](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2021#august_23_2021)). This might explain the issue.

I don't think that there might a workaround to use Google Apps Script or the Documents API to copy a dropdown without having the erro.

Resources

- [Insert smart chips & building blocks in your Google Doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10710316?hl=en)

Related

- [How to insert RichLink (Chip Block) in Google Docs using Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69784306/1595451)
- [Get Google "pills" value as Plain text from Google docs with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71087333/1595451)
- [How to get in Apps Script the value of a dropdown in a Google Doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72914087/1595451)